# I want to compare text in two columns and return a value in a third column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a recurring spreadsheet I need to analyze:

To see if any or part of the text in column H matches the phrases listed in cells K2:K13. If they do I would like Yes to appear in column I.

I am currently using a separate conditional formatting rule (does H contain text in K2...K13 if yes format green) for each phrase in column K on column H and manually marking all the cells in column I Yes if the cell next in H is green.

[Screen Grab of Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W31iL.png)

I have also tried XLOOKUP but that will only return a true value if there's an exact match. These cells in H can have some or all of the phrases in the K column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

=IF(EXACT(G8, H8), "yes","No")
Try this method please.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This will not work as it will only return a yes if there is an exact match. As I stated my problem is getting it to return a yes when there's a partial match.